# Xamarin Forms how to consume a wcf service

Tags: wcf, xamarin.forms

I've created a Xamarin project which added the following projects to the solution:

Xamarin.UI(Portable)

Xamarin.UI.Droid

Xamarin.UI.iOS

Xamarin.UI.UWP

Xamarin.UI.Windows (Windows 8.1)

Xamarin.UI.WindowsPhone (Windows Phone 8.1)

I am having problems creating a client which can consume my WCF service.

1) Firstly the current Xamarin project template doesn't reference System.ServiceModel assembly in the PCL therefore I cannot right click the PCL and Add Service Reference to my project. When I manually add a reference to System.ServiceModel from this location - C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5 the menu item for create service reference pops up. When I click Go in the Add Service Reference dialog I get the following error:

"This service cannot be consumed by the current project. Please check if the project target framework supports this service type."

The PCL targets are as follows:

.NET Framework 4.5

ASP.NET Core 1.0

Windows 8

Windows Phone 8.1

Xamarin.Android

Xamarin.iOS

Xamarin.iOS

I don't know how to get this working ?

2) Secondly the work around I use is to create the client with SlSvcUtil.exe
Add the generated code to my PCL along with a reference to System.ServiceModel and everything builds ok. The problem is that when I run the code it flags up type reference errors ! Should I be manually adding the reference to System.ServiceModel anyway? What am I doing wrong in this scenario? Am I missing some steps?

I've checked the Xamarin docs but it seems that I can't find detailed instructions on this.

Please help me out ! Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCL and WCF should be supported. Alternatively, you could get this to work manually with HttpClient, etc. But maybe if you can use the shared project instead of PCL, that would be easier. Otherwise you'd have to also use DependencyService, create interfaces, etc. for each platform.

Comment: thanks Joe, using httpclient means i'll have to manually de-serialize objects from XML - ahhh man. Using shared project means I have to convert everything - but it could work. There must be a way to get WCF + PCL working

Comment: this link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19303/how-to-consume-wcf-service-in-xamarin-forms-pcl discusses that they got it working, but don't provide thorough enough details on it.

Comment: Whoops, looks like I searched for the wrong acronyms. Yes WCF is supported in certain PCLs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx Can you check the PCL profile number to make absolutely sure you're targeting the right one?

Comment: Looking at the link, am I right in stating that WCF isn't supported by Windows Phone 8.1 in PCL? It seems thats the case, I might have to convert the project to win phone silverlight instead, though I don't know what the exact diff is. I can't find the profile number, where can I find it, I've stated the targets in the question is that what you mean?

Comment: Ah that might do it, having support for WP8.1 seems like the culprit. Can you not select WP8.1 and see if you can get it to at least compile? You can find the profile number inside the .csproj file, it's not readily available in the VS UI, but I think it might be in the XS. I really only requested it to verify the profile you're on.

Comment: <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>10.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile111</TargetFrameworkProfile>                    Here's the info. I'll defo try to compile without WP8.1 and see If I can at least get data over the wire with UWP / Droid and iOS. What if it can't support WP8.1 do you think if I changed over to Shared project it should work at least in theory for all platforms?

Comment: It would be easier to create a quick test app targeting the non-WP8.1 platforms. I don't see why shared project wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi Joe, I've created a test shared project. I've created the wcf client and pasted the code and config file in the shared project but it won't compile. I've tried adding references to system.serviceModel to each of the projects that reference the shared project but it still won't pick up the referenced assemblies.

Comment: Is that new project Profile111 too? That doesn't have WCF according to http://danrigby.com/2014/04/16/xamarin-pcl-profile-notes/ Can you change the profile to something else that does? For me, all the assemblies get added for me by default in XS.

Comment: Great I got it to work finally. Win Phone 8.1 WinRT does not support WCF however Win Phone 8.1 Silverlight does support it. All I had to do was to change the profile of the PCL to 78, add service reference and UWP, Droid, Win 8, iOS all working now. I added a win phone Silverlight project as the pcl78 supports it heres how I added it - http://motzcod.es/post/122783563052/guide-to-add-windows-phone-to-xamarinforms-13. Thanks for all your help Joe